# Call .fail(error) without throwing exception

Tags: c#, exception, signalr, signalr.client

Using SignalR, is there any possibility to call `.fail` instead of `.done` when specific values are returned by hub method?

Perhaps using the SignalR pipeline?

```
public bool Delete(int addressId)
{
    // User should not be able to delete default address
    if(AddressService.IsDefaultAddressOfCustomer(addressId))
        return false; // Should call .fail() on client

    AddressService.Delete(addressId);
    return true; // Should call .done() on client
}
```

The alternative would be to throw an exception but I would like to avoid that since the error is not really a server fault, but a user fault.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are really convinced an exception is not the right tool for you, you could use some custom attribute you would define to mark methods where a `false` return value must be translated into an error, and then intercept any incoming call with `BuildIncoming` from `HubPipelineModule`:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.hubpipelinemodule.buildincoming(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.hubpipelinemodule.buildincoming%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

From inside there you can intercept the call to your original method, inspect if it's marked with your attribute and if it returned `false`, if it's the case you can throw an exception from there. The bottom line is, you would still throw an exception to make it call `.fail()` client-side, but that exception would not bloat your business logic. Something like this:

```
public class FailPipelineModule : HubPipelineModule
{
    public override Func<IHubIncomingInvokerContext, Task<object>> BuildIncoming(Func<IHubIncomingInvokerContext, Task<object>> invoke)
    {
        return base.BuildIncoming(context =>
        {
            var r = (bool)(invoke(context)).Result;
            if (context.MethodDescriptor.Attributes.Any(a => typeof(FailAttribute) == a.GetType()) && !r)
                throw new ApplicationException("false");
            return Task.FromResult((object)r);
        });
    }
}
```

You'll need to define `FailAttribute`, use it to mark your hub's method and register `FailPipelineModule` at startup.

Answer (score 0):

As Wasp indicated, with the SignalR JavaScript client, the promise is only rejected if `hubResult.Error` is set, which only happens when an exception is thrown while the request is processed. There's no way to modify that using the hub pipeline.

In general, I'd probably stick with using exceptions in that case, but if you're looking for another alternative, you could also modify the client-side `jquery.signalr-*.js` code, specifically the hubProxy prototype `invoke` method. It has a condition to decide whether to resolve or reject the promise:

```
if (result.Error) {
   // code to reject ...
} else {
    connection.log("Invoked " + that.hubName + "." + methodName);
    d.resolveWith(that, [result.Result]);
}
```

and you could modify the else block:

```
if (result.Error) {
    // code to reject ...
} else {
    connection.log("Invoked " + that.hubName + "." + methodName);
    if (typeof result.Result === "boolean" && !result.Result) {
        d.rejectWith(that, [result.Result]);
    } else {
        d.resolveWith(that, [result.Result]);
    }
}
```

Then all hub methods which return false would reject the promise. 
The advantage over Wasp's solution would be not having to create attributes and overall less code. The drawback is that it might be less maintainable since you're manually editing the SignalR code (so if you do that, it should definitely be documented somewhere, and you'd have to minify the script yourself instead of using the packaged one).

A more maintainable client-side alternative would be to wrap the hub API and return your own deferred from that, e.g. like this:

```
var myHub = {
    server: $.connection.myHub.server,
    init: function() {
        for (var methodName in this.server) {
            if (this.server.hasOwnProperty(methodName)) {
                this[methodName] = function() {
                    var deferred = $.Deferred();
                    this.server[methodName].apply(this.server, arguments)
                        .done(function(result) {
                            // reject if server hub method returned false
                            if (result === false) deferred.reject(result);
                            deferred.resolve(result);
                        });

                    return deferred.promise();
                };
            }
        }
    }
};
myHub.init();
```

Then instead of calling

```
$.connection.myHub.server.someMethod("hello", "world")
    .done(function(result) { })
    .fail(function(result) { });
```

you would call

```
myHub.someMethod("hello", "world")
    .done(function(result) { })
    .fail(function(result) { });
```

That way, you'd have full control over how return values are interpreted.

Comment: This one is interesting too. I would add that maybe just testing for a boolean could be too greedy (maybe not every method returning `false` represents a *failure*), but it's true that, if the option of editing SignalR is acceptable, you can still make this behavior *optional* by using some *opt in* callback specified through SignalR's startup options. This way some further check on things like, for example, the method's name to decide if a `false` means a failure would not get lost into SignalR's codebase, bubbling up into the application specific code.

Comment: I'd only do this when there is a contract that all hub methods (at least for a given hub) return false to indicate failure. Having some methods that return false as a valid value and some that use it to indicate a failure condition is confusing to read and work with. In that case, throwing an exception is much easier to understand.

Comment: Agree, but still it could be a problem to constraint that to "a given hub" because the mod to SignalR's plugin would not distinguish that and apply the logic to every hub. That's why the idea of exctacting that piece out.

Comment: yup, using a separate and external function to determine the validity of the result certainly is a good suggestion for an actual implementation - my code was only intended to outline the idea in the shortest manner possible