# C# signalR making requests fail

Tags: c#, exception, signalr

So I have a custom pipeline which I built and since my entire program not catching any exceptions (on purpese) I would like to catch them in a higher level than the Hub's.

I have `public sealed class CommonPipelineModule : HubPipelineModule` which contains the method `public override Func<IHubIncomingInvokerContext, Task<object>> BuildIncoming(Func<IHubIncomingInvokerContext, Task<object>> invoke)`.

The code looks like:

```
public sealed class CommonPipelineModule : HubPipelineModule
{
    public override Func<IHubIncomingInvokerContext, Task<object>> BuildIncoming(Func<IHubIncomingInvokerContext, Task<object>> invoke)
    {
        return base.BuildIncoming(async context =>
        {
            Func<Task<object>> myInvoker = async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return await invoke(context);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return new FailureResponseObject(e as dynamic, e.Message);
                }

            };
            return await myInvoker();
        }
    }
}
```

FailureResponseObject knows how to handle the exception and creates an object which the client will be more comfortable with.

Problem is: I want the client to receive the object in the `fail` callback rather than in the `success` one.

So I figured I can just throw an exception instead of returning the custom object to get to the `fail` callback, but I would like to handle this in my pipeline rather in some upper layer.

Im looking for some context status changing or something similar, perhaps like changing the http response code in HTTP requests.

There is this post: [Call .fail(error) without throwing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991242/call-failerror-without-throwing-exception) but perhaps something has changed 2 years later in Signalr 2.0 (which is what im using)